# MoviePy RuntimeError: imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated

Tags: python, runtime-error, moviepy, python-imageio

I try to run a simple script in Google Colab to determine a length of a video:

```
!pip install moviepy
from moviepy.editor import *
# Change directory:
os.chdir(r'/content/my_data')
clip = VideoFileClip("my_video.mp4")
print(clip.duration)
```

However, I obtain an error:
`imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. Use 'pip install imageio-ffmpeg' instead.'`

After quick search I found that `imageio` needs to be downgraded by doing this:
`!pip install imageio==2.4.1`

So I changed the scrip to following:

```
!pip install moviepy
!pip install imageio==2.4.1
from moviepy.editor import *
# Change directory:
os.chdir(r'/content/my_data')
clip = VideoFileClip("my_video.mp4")
print(clip.duration)
```

I am still getting the same error.

Any idea how to fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As moviepy is not in great shape nowadays I would recommend just using imageio's V2 API for the time being. It is really easy to get the metadata from a video file using it. Basically,

```
import imageio
path = "path/to/videofile.mp4"
video = imageio.get_reader(path)

print(video._meta)
```

Using the meta attribute you can access the number of frames, codec, size, etc. If you only want to get the duration (in seconds) you can just simply call for:

```
print(video._meta["duration"])
```

Answer (score 2):

@Mr K.'s answer is correct; however, in modern versions of ImageIO you can use this alternative, which may be simpler:

```py
import imageio.v3 as iio

location = "path/to/videofile.mp4"
duration = iio.immeta(location)["duration"]
print(duration)
```

([`immeta`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_autosummary/imageio.v3.immeta.html#imageio.v3.immeta) reads the metadata of an image or video.)

Comment: Thank you for providing the V3 API version of the code!